# Como fazer update usando três tabelas no ORACLE

Tags: oracle, sql-update

Preciso fazer update, só que no where envolve três tabelas diferentes para pegar o campo que preciso e estou com dificuldade para achar a solução!

```
     update sspess pess             
     inner join ssusua usua on pess.nnumepess = usua.nnumepess
     inner join ssfonp hss  on pess.nnumepess = hss.nnumepess   
     set usua.cmailusua = 'teste@gmail.com'               
     where usua.csituusua = 'A'            AND 
           hss.cprinfonp  = 'S'            AND 
           usua.dpvalusua < sysdate        AND 
           pess.ccpf_pess = '11111111111';
```

O banco é oracle.

Comment: *"estou com dificuldade para achar a solução"* e qual é a dificuldade, eu vejo que já tem ai as 3 tabelas

Comment: de funcionar! Quando executa a query da erro!
ORA-00971: palavra-chave SET não encontrada.

Comment: o problema é que essa sintaxe não funciona no `oracle`, após o `UPDATE` deve vir o `SET`. No seu caso, como precisa de 3 tabelas, faz sentido juntar as 3 usar parênteses pra pegar os resultados das tabelas, algo assim: `UPDATE (select sspess inner join ....... ) tabelas SET tabelas.cmailusua = 'teste@gmail.com'  WHERE.....`

Answer (score -1):

No Oracle, o comando update não aceita a cláusula FROM.

Porém, se repararmos bem no seu update, ele aponta para a tabela sspess, mas o valor é atribuído na tabela usua, o que não faz muito sentido.

Imagino que o correto seria algo do tipo:

```
update ssusua usua set
  cmailusua = 'teste@gmail.com'
where
  nnumepess in ( select pess.nnumepess
                 from
                   ssfonp hss,
                   sspess pess
                 where
                   pess.ccpf_pess = '11111111111' and
                   hss.nnumepess = pess.nnumepess and
                   hss.cprinfonp = 'S' ) and
  csituusua = 'A' and
  dpvalusua < sysdate;
```

Além disso, mas não acho que seja o caso aqui, o Oracle pode executar um update em uma subquery. O exemplo abaixo mostra como seria esta funcionalidade:

```
UPDATE ( SELECT product_id, category_id 
         FROM product 
         WHERE category_id = 4 ) 
SET category_id = 5;
```

Para que esta funcionalidade seja válida, a lista de colunas retornadas pela subquery precisa incluir colunas que identifiquem unicamente a linha da tabela  cujas colunas serão atualizadas.